# Excel 2013 Power Query

Tags: power, active-directory, contacts, users, query

Does anyone know how to extract all Active Directory Users and show which ones are Users and which ones are just Contacts. 
I've extracted both Users and Contacts but they seem to show the same in both lists. I'm struggling to find a string to use to decided if this is a User or just a Contact. Anyone managed to do this?